# Use vim in a 64bits environment

Tags: windows, vim, 64-bit, uac

I installed **windows8** on my system.
Then I installed VIM in **program files (x86)**.

I noted that I have to run VIM always as administrator to be enable to modify files.
I resolved this *right clicking on gvim.exe --> properties --> compatibility --> run this program as administrator*.
Is that the correct way?
How did you resolve this problem?

I still receive the UAC prompt every time I start vim.
Is there a way to avoid this prompt?

Comment: http://www.petri.co.il/disable-uac-in-windows-7.htm - it's the same for Win8

Comment: It might also be possible to use the task scheduler to allow running the program with admin rights, and then using a special link. ( This works for Windows 7, and might also work for Windows 8: http://maximumpcguides.com/windows-vista/run-a-program-with-administrative-privileges-without-uac-prompts/ )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not need admin rights in order to run Vim. (Except for when you edit system files or update Vim's runtime itself.)

It looks like Vim wants to modify something inside its runtime directories, which causes Windows to display the UAC prompt. Have you created a `vimfiles` folder in your user's directory? Does Vim start up in `C:\WINDOWS` or somewhere in `C:\Program Files (x86)\`? Try changing the shortcut that launches Vim to change the working directory to your user's directory.

If you want to make changes to Vim's runtime files, create a user-specific vimrc in `C:\Users\<username>\_vimrc` instead of editing the one provided by Vim (same for other files like `menu.vim`; put them into `C:\Users\<username>\vimfiles\...`); this way, you have clean separation, avoid problems when upgrading Vim, and won't get the UAC prompt.

Comment: You're right it only gives problems when I try to change the .vimrc or menu.vim file (they are in the vim directory in "program files (x86)". It works fine when I edit a file on another drive. What do you do to edit the .vimrc file? Do you run vim as administrator?

Comment: No, you should make copies of the files in your home directory. See `:help vimrc`; I've extended my answer, too.

Comment: thank you, but how do you test these files to see if they work? Do you copy them everytime to the vim directory in program files?

Comment: No, they are picked up automatically from those locations! That's the difference between system- and user-config. You can check with `:scriptnames`.

Comment: I'm trying to find out how to put _vimrc in a subdirectory of $HOME. I have to set an environment variable $VIMINIT but don't know where to set this environment variable

Comment: there is no way to move the menu.vim file to $HOME directory.

Comment: any idea Ingo? I moved menu.vim to <username>\vimfiles as you've indicated in your mail but that doesn't work. Error message: can't find menu.vim in `c:\program files (x86)\vim\vim73`

Comment: Don't move it there, just put your own modifications into `~/vimfiles/mymenu.vim`, and `:runtime! mymenu.vim` it from your `.vimrc`. If you don't want any items of the default menu, remove them with `:aunmenu *` as the first command in your script.